# Using BERT embeddings as input for transformer architecture

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings, bert, transformer

I will use BERT's embedding weights (as discussed [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-get-embedding-matrix-of-bert-in-hugging-face/10261/4)) for embedding in embedding layers of the transformer model. But my question is: don't embeddings of BERT already go through the whole encoding layer and got that matrix? Why shouldn't I just remove-freeze the encoding layer and use BERT embedding vectors as input for the decoding layer? And also I will use BERT embeddings in the input of the decoding layer. Why should I not freeze attention layers in decoder layer too? Because embeddings of output text already have attention information?

Comment: What is your final objective? Do you want to fine-tune a Bert model or train one from scratch?

Comment: @NicolasMartin I want to use pre-trained word embeddings and a pre-trained BERT encoder in transformers.